# (Typescript) Cleanest way to provide my own typings for firestore snapshot?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

```
interface Doc {
  foo: {
    bar: number;
  };
}
const docSnapshot = await docRef.get();
const bar = docSnapshot.get("foo.bar") as Doc["foo"]["bar"];
```

I know the type of my data, and this is how I'm casting it when retrieving from firestore snapshot. It's a little verbose. Is there a simpler way to say "I know the snapshot data is `Doc`"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to assume that the entire snapshot is an object structured like `Doc`, this is very common:

```
const docSnapshot = await docRef.get();
const doc = docSnapshot.data() as Doc;
const bar = doc.foo.bar;
```

So, instead of trying to reach into a specific field using `get('a.b')`, just use `data()` to get the entire document object object outright, and use it like you would any other JavaScript object with nested properties.

Comment: I assume there's no performance difference between `snapshot.data()` and `snapshot.get('foo.bar')`? The doc didn't say, but since `ref.get()` is asynchronous and `snapshot.data()` is synchronous, I assume the snapshot already retrieved all the data?

Comment: After you call get(), the entire document is in memory in the returned DocumentSnapshot.  data() just returns a JS object with all of that data.